# Limit one item in the accordion to uncollapsed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

All the collapsible items should not collapse. At-least one of the items should stay uncollapsed. I want to change the following example to fulfill my needs. I will appreciate any help!

```
/*\Animate collapsible set;\*/

$(document).one("pagebeforechange", function () {
    // animation speed;
    var animationSpeed = 200;

    function animateCollapsibleSet(elm) {
        // can attach events only one time, otherwise we create infinity loop;
        elm.one("expand", function () {
            // hide the other collapsibles first;
            $(this).parent().find(".ui-collapsible-content").not(".ui-collapsible-content-collapsed").trigger("collapse");
            // animate show on collapsible;
            $(this).find(".ui-collapsible-content").slideDown(animationSpeed, function () {
                // trigger original event and attach the animation again;
                animateCollapsibleSet($(this).parent().trigger("expand"));
            });
            // we do our own call to the original event;
            return false;
        }).one("collapse", function () {
            // animate hide on collapsible;
            $(this).find(".ui-collapsible-content").slideUp(animationSpeed, function () {
                // trigger original event;
                $(this).parent().trigger("collapse");
            });
            // we do our own call to the original event;
            return false;
        });
    }
    // init;
    animateCollapsibleSet($("[data-role='collapsible-set'] > [data-role='collapsible']"));
});
```

Here is a working example on animating a collapsible set: http://jsfiddle.net/jerone/gsNzT/

Comment: this expands one and collapse the rest, what do you need exactly? you always want one collapsable expanded?

Comment: if one item is expanded and i click the same element to collapse then it should not collapse (current not the case in this example). But if i click some other item, the current expanded item should collapse (as the example does).

Comment: Then you need to integrate your code above with the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/20002186/1771795

Comment: yes it worked...i was already using the code you mentioned....but some how it did not worked...now its working...thanks Omar!

Answer (score 0):

So you don't want to allow that all the items are collapsed? I would do it like this:
Catch the collapsing event and then:

1. if collapsing item is currently expanded (`.attr('data-collapsed') == "true"`) then return false and prevent collapsing
2. if collapsing item is not urrently expanded, it's ok, it will collapse, and another item will expand

You might be considered to check this: [How do I restrict a collapsible item to stay expanded...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19999841/how-do-i-restrict-a-collapsible-item-to-stay-expanded-unless-i-click-the-other-c?rq=1)

also check in jquery mobile documentation if there is already implemented method for this